# C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' & C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, forms, qt

First of all, i've seen some solutions, but i didn't understand them. I am a total Newbie in QT and even Google didn't helped me. English is not my first language

This is the error message after debugging in QT Creator 5.6

> C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
>
> C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

here is the file

secdialog.h

```
#ifndef SECDIALOG_H
#define SECDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "tridialog.h"
#include "quadialog.h"

namespace Ui {
class SecDialog;
}

class SecDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SecDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SecDialog();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_5_clicked();

    void on_status_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_zuteilung_clicked();

private:
    Ui::SecDialog *ui;

    TriDialog *triDialog;  //this is the line with the problem

    QuaDialog *quaDialog;  // funny thing, he didn't complain about this line

};

#endif // SECDIALOG_H
```

Sorry if the problem was already here in the questions, but i didn't understand the other solutions.

I'm trying to make a little program just for show, it only needs to show some forms and thats it. There are some buttons and every button opens another form and hides the one before.

My problem is, i always have my problems with programming and languages, often i don't know enough to understand a solution, i'm more a "someone shows me how and then i use it and understand it" - i learn through "copy paste"

Could anyone tell me what i did wrong?
If you need more information about the project, just ask.

Thank you in advance.

Here the the requested tridialog.h

```
#ifndef TRIDIALOG_H
#define TRIDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "secdialog.h"


namespace Ui {
class TriDialog;
}

class TriDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TriDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~TriDialog();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_5_clicked();

private:
    Ui::TriDialog *ui;
    TriDialog *triDialog;
};

#endif // TRIDIALOG_H
```

Here is the whole project for qt [kraftwerk.zip](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02052917509199299561)

Comment: What does `"tridialog.h"` look like?

Comment: edited the post... tridialog.h is now there

Comment: @barry Is this legal? `explicit TriDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in `tridialog.h`:

```
#include "secdialog.h"
```

When you include `secdialog.h`, you bring in your `SecDialog` class declaration, which has a `TriDialog` pointer (on the problematic line) before the `TriDialog` class is declared!

Since you don't actually need anything from `secdialog.h` in `tridialog.h`, just remove

```
#include "secdialog.h"
```

and it should work.

Comment: Good catch. That looks like the problem Tareen was looking for.

Comment: When i delete the #include following errorcode comes

Comment: moc_secdialog.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl SecDialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_2_clicked@SecDialog@@AEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl SecDialog::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@SecDialog@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

Comment: moc_secdialog.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl SecDialog::on_zuteilung_clicked(void)" (?on_zuteilung_clicked@SecDialog@@AEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl SecDialog::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@SecDialog@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

Comment: Those are linker errors, which is a different problem. You have probably not defined the functions SecDialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked() and SecDialog::on_zuteilung_clicked() yet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a scoping error, unless I'm misunderstanding your intent. This code:

```
namespace Ui {
    class TriDialog;
}

class TriDialog : public QDialog
{};
```

declares a class named `TriDialog` in the namespace `Ui` and then declares a class named `TriDialog` outside the namespace `Ui`. You now have two classes, `Ui::TriDialog` and `TriDialog`. You need to put the whole definition inside the namespace scope.

**Edit:**
Looks like skearney found the error you were asking about, but this is still an issue.